# What is replacement of "setKeys:(NSArray *)keys triggerChangeNotificationsForDependentKey:(NSString *)dependentKey" in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I have code of setKeys: triggerChangeNotificationsForDependentKey: method as

```
[CKTransferRecord setKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"progress"] triggerChangeNotificationsForDependentKey:@"nameWithProgress"]; 
[CKTransferRecord setKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"progress", @"name", @"size", nil] triggerChangeNotificationsForDependentKey:@"nameWithProgressAndFileSize"];
```

But i don't know what is replacement of this. Because this method is deprecated method. What is replacement of this code? Please help me.

Comment: It's [all in the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueObserving_Protocol/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html)...  `keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey:` is the suggested method for 10.5+

Comment: Thanks Alladinian. But how to use keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey: method. Please explain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Registering Dependent Keys](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVODependentKeys.html) in the [Key-Value Observing Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html).

When something key-value observes a property of your class, the framework will invoke `+keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey:` on your class to learn what other key paths affect that property. KVO therefore implicitly observes those other key paths and, when one of them changes, generates change notifications for the originally-observed property, too.

One way to implement this is to override `+keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey:` in your class. Call `super`. After that, compare the `key` argument to see if it matches one of your properties. If it does and that property depends on other key paths, then add those key paths into the set returned from `super`'s implementation.

However, there's a simpler shortcut. The default implementation of `+keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey:` will invoke `+keyPathsForValuesAffecting<Key>` if your class implements it. So, you can just implement

```
+ (NSSet*) keyPathsForValuesAffectingNameWithProgress
{
    return [NSSet setWithObject:@"progress"];
}

+ (NSSet*) keyPathsForValuesAffectingNameWithProgressAndFileSize
{
    return [NSSet setWithObjects:@"progress", @"name", @"size", nil];
}
```

I find it's most useful to implement those methods right next to the implementation of the getter for the property which references those other key paths. That way they can be viewed and updated together.